# Proper way to build custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, subclass

I've been wondering about `UITableView`'s and their cells for a while. `UITableView` is a very handy UIView subclass, but there is a lot of predetermined/forced content on a `UITableViewCell`. I was wondering what is the best way to create a custom `UIView` (which will end up being a `UITableViewCell`) for `UITableView`?

The cell has a certain style that has to be set and there are predetermined `UILabel`s and accessory views that are completely immutable, other than their contents. I find this to be a big waste, but just giving the cell a custom content view (and background view, if one pleases) doesn't prevent or remove these processes or restore the memory.

Is there any way to create a lighter version of a `UITableViewCell` subclass? Or is there a way to use a UIView with a selection method instead (other than essentially creating a custom `UITableView` using `UIScrollView`)?

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: UITableView is a UIScrollView subclass, not a UIView subclass.

Comment: @max_ And UIScrollView is a subclass of UIView, so I went down two levels from UITableView.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But a UITableView isn't a subclass of UIView.

Comment: Well, a subclass is a class that inherits its superclass and adds more to it, so while its not a direct subclass of UIView, it is still an indirect subclass of UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an answer for this. UITableViewCells will always have UILabels and other views automatically added to them. I'm not sure if they are allocated before you set them, though. They may have custom setting / allocation methods.

Comment: Well, the labels and accessories are properties. That means they are always accessible. Accessing the textLabel and detailsTextLabel and setting the text will instantly set the text without any allocation or setting of frames on my part. This either means that the labels are preset/preallocated, or they have custom setText functions that allocate them if they weren't previously allocated (since I'm sure apple wouldn't reallocate on top of a previous allocation).

Comment: It's easy to verify that `UITableViewCell`'s doing lazy loading with a few minutes in the debugger. You can add whatever content you want to the `contentView`, or subclass and add whatever other properties you want, and the label referred to by the `textLabel` will still never get allocated. So the correct answer to your question is "Don't use what you don't need."

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods:

From a XIB file:

- [ios steps to create custom UITableViewCell with xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917027/ios-steps-to-create-custom-uitableviewcell-with-xib-file)
- http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

Using Drawing:

- http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318 (4th and 5th examples)