# how to add 5 different custom cells in tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview

I want to show different data from web in my tableview but I am not getting how to show them in separate cells in one section of a table can any one help me to show 
in one cell

```
cell.textLabel.text=app.i_name;
```

in second cell

```
cell.textLabel.text=app.i_phone;
```

in third cell

```
cell.textLabel.text=app.i_hours;
```

in forth cell

```
cell.textLabel.text=app.i_address;
```

in fifth cell

```
cell.textLabel.text=app.i_email;
```

my cell for row at index is as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Single Cell";
    SingleCell *cell =(SingleCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SingleCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = (SingleCell *) c.view;
        //[c release];

    }
appDC * application = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        //cell.namelbl.text=application.application_name;


return cell;
}
```

Comment: IMHO if you accept a few more answers you'll get a lot more help. That's just been my experience on SO.

Comment: Also, are you asking how to create 5 different custom cells or how just change the data with the "stock iOS" UITableViewCells?

Comment: i am trying to save my time by only creating one custom cell but if you have idea to show it with 5 more custom cells its ok

Comment: I was just trying to get a better idea of what you are trying to do; the answer below is the way to go!

Comment: i'm already edit my answer. Let's try it again. Cheers!

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it strange that a `UIViewController` is being created for each cell?

Comment: yes i am also surprised but i think i have no other option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Single Cell";
    SingleCell *cell =(SingleCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SingleCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = (SingleCell *) c.view;
        //[c release];

    }
    appDC * application = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    //cell.namelbl.text=application.application_name;
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text=application.i_name;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = application.i_iphone;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = application.i_hours;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = application.i_address;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = application.i_email;
    }



    return cell;
}
```

Hope this answer will help. Cheers

Comment: i already tried this it dosn t work it only give me first cell :(

Comment: Could you try again? I'm did not used same object to pass value to textLabel. So, are you sure your object property is type of NSString ?

Comment: I believe the asker is trying to get all the data from each element in the array into one cell... I assume the reason this only gave him the first cell is because his array only has one element in it and when the app tries to populate the table it only gives him the first cell. A custom cell will definitely need to be created to accommodate all the data in the "application" object being extracted from the array "dataArray" Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917027/ios-steps-to-create-custom-uitableviewcell-with-xib-file

Comment: Hi El Guapo, if the asker mean like your comment should be keep track on the way you suggestion. Best :)

Answer (score 2):

i solved this question by doing this code thanks for all giving suggestion

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellForInfo";
    CellForInfo *cell =(CellForInfo *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CellForInfo" bundle:nil];
        cell = (CellForInfo *) c.view;
        //[c release];



     }

    appDC * application = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.lblinfo.text=application.i_name;
    }
     if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.lblinfo.text = application.i_phone;
    }
     if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cell.lblinfo.text = application.i_hours;
    }
     if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        cell.lblinfo.text = application.i_address;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        cell.lblinfo.text = application.i_email;
    }



    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IKQ's code example should work. But I suggest to try my [TableKit](https://github.com/onegray/UITableKit) library. This way the code will be more clear and elegant:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TKStaticCell* nameCell = [TKStaticCell cellWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 text:@"Name" detailText:app.i_name];
    TKStaticCell* phoneCell = [TKStaticCell cellWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 text:@"Phone" detailText:app.i_phone];
    TKStaticCell* hoursCell = [TKStaticCell cellWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 text:@"Hours" detailText:app.i_hours];
    TKStaticCell* addressCell = [TKStaticCell cellWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 text:@"Address" detailText:app.i_address];
    TKStaticCell* emailCell = [TKStaticCell cellWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 text:@"email" detailText:app.i_email];
    TKSection* section = [TKSection sectionWithCells:nameCell, phoneCell, hoursCell, addressCell, emailCell, nil];
    self.sections = [NSArray arrayWithObject:section];
}
```

Also the library allows to define custom cell instead of `TKStaticCell`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for short

```
            CellForInfo * cellForInfo = (CellForInfo *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

            if (cellForInfo ==nil) {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellForInfo" owner:self options:nil];
                cellForInfo = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self tableInfo];
}


- (void) tableInfo
{

    NSArray *keysArray = @[@"CampaignsName",@"BusinessName",@"BusinessType",@"CampaignsType",@"Distance",@"Daysleft",@"CampaignImage",];

    NSArray *valuesArray1 =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"5 % OFF ",@"Coffe Shop",@"1",@"1",@"0.10 Miles",@"5 days Left",@"b2.png", nil];

    NSArray *valuesArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"win $2 for you & charity ",@"Red Tommato",@"2",@"2",@"20 Miles",@"2 days Left",@"b1.png", nil];

    NSArray *valuesArray3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Buy dogs food & get a one more",@"Pet Care",@"3",@"3", @"30 Miles",@"10 days Left",@"b2.png", nil];

    NSArray *valuesArray4 =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"win $2 for you & charity ",@"Red Tommato",@"1",@"1",@"0.10 Miles",@"7 days Left",@"b2.png", nil];



    NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valuesArray1 forKeys:keysArray];

    NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valuesArray2 forKeys:keysArray];

    NSDictionary *dict3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valuesArray3 forKeys:keysArray];

    NSDictionary *dict4 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valuesArray4 forKeys:keysArray];



    self.tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4,dict3,dict1,dict4,dict2,nil];
    NSLog(@"Array %@",tableArray);
    [self.tableObj reloadData];
}

#pragma  mark table view datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.tableArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableCustomView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableCustomView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *mainCell ;



    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"CustomCellIdentifier";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"CustomCellIdentifier2";


    if (indexPath.row % 2 != 0)
    {
        CustomCell2 *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell2 == nil)
        {

            NSArray *topObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell2" owner:self options:nil];
            cell2 = [topObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }


        id object = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        cell2.CampaignsNameLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"CampaignsName"]];
        cell2.BusinessNameLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"BusinessName"]];
        cell2.DistanceLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"Distance"]];
        cell2.DaysleftLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"Daysleft"]];

        cell2.cellBackImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"CampaignImage"]]];


        int businessType = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"BusinessType"]] integerValue];

        NSLog(@": %d",businessType);

        switch (businessType)
        {


            case 1:

                cell2.cellBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RETL@2x.png"];

                break;
            case 2:

                cell2.cellBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BTY.png"];

                break;
            case 3:

                cell2.cellBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t1.png"];

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


        int CampaignsType = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"CampaignsType"]] integerValue];

        switch (CampaignsType)
        {

            case 1:

                cell2.cellOverLayBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t3.png"];

                break;
            case 2:

                cell2.cellOverLayBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t2.png"];

                break;
            case 3:

                cell2.cellOverLayBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t1.png"];

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        mainCell = cell2 ;


    }

    else
    {
        CustomCell1 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell1 == nil)
        {

            NSArray *topObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell1" owner:self options:nil];
            cell1 = [topObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }


        id object = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        cell1.CampaignsNameLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"CampaignsName"]];
        cell1.BusinessNameLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"BusinessName"]];
        cell1.DistanceLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"Distance"]];
        cell1.DaysleftLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"Daysleft"]];

        cell1.cellBackImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"CampaignImage"]]];


        int businessType = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"BusinessType"]] integerValue];

        NSLog(@": %d",businessType);

        switch (businessType)
        {


            case 1:

                cell1.cellBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RETL@2x.png"];

                break;
            case 2:

                cell1.cellBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BTY.png"];

                break;
            case 3:

                cell1.cellBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t1.png"];

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


        int CampaignsType = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"CampaignsType"]] integerValue];

        switch (CampaignsType)
        {

            case 1:

                cell1.cellOverLayBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t3.png"];

                break;
            case 2:

                cell1.cellOverLayBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t2.png"];

                break;
            case 3:

                cell1.cellOverLayBusinessTypeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t1.png"];

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        mainCell = cell1 ;
    }


    return mainCell;

    NSLog(@"Index Path is :%d %d", indexPath.section,indexPath.row);
}
```