# Accessing UITableViewCell subclass outlet properties

Tags: ios, uitableview

I provided a `UITableViewCell` subclass `MyCell` with outlet properties (in order to hook up the nib):

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* theLabel;

@end
```

I then synthesize `theLabel`.
I then want to use the property name to access the cell:

```
MyCell *theCell = (MyCell *)cell;
UILabel *lab = theCell.theLabel;
```

When I use the property name to access the cell I receive an error message:

`[UITableViewCell theLabel]: unrecognized selector`

I seem to be missing something. Why does it throw an exception?

Comment: Apparently, `cell` is of type `UITableViewCell *`, and not `MyCell *`. I. e., it's not actually an instance of your custom class, just an instance of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Are you creating the cell in a storyboard or xib file or programatically?

Comment: Creating the cell in a xib file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that within your cellForRowAtIndexPath function you are not correctly instantiating the cell to your "MyCell" type but rather just trying to static cast the pointer to it. In the end you trying to access a property that doesn't exist in a plain UITableViewCell.

Are you loading your cell similar to this?:

```
static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: I am loading the cell like this: `    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     MyCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 `

Comment: Why are you showing a cast in your original code? Maybe try this: if([cell isKindOf:[MyCell class]]){ NSLog(@"I am the correct cell type"; } and see if you are correctly typed at that point. If that fails then it is something to do with your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. You are correct, I am not correctly typed. So I am instantiating incorrectly and just static casting the pointer to it. How can I set up correctly?

Comment: I would recommend just going through all of the steps and see what you did wrong. There are plenty of tutorials like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917027/ios-steps-to-create-custom-uitableviewcell-with-xib-file