# Custom Cell Storyboard Issues

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am trying to create a custom cell for a table view.  I have found this great tutorial, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html
but am having problems.

In my existing code, I have been using xib files.  (I do not want to change everything into storyboard.  There are a lot of xib in my project).  However, I noticed that using a storyboard is needed to create a custom cell.  I have added a storyboard to my project as well as a .h and .m files and follwoed the tuorial.  However, when I run the code and try to get to the table, I am getting a "Could not find a storyboard named ...)

I am trying to present that view controller with the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TestStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyController"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I have checked the build phases and do see my storyboard in there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Storyboard is not needed for custom cells it's needed for PrototyeCells....For your problem just create another empty xib file and add tableViewCell in it from interface builder.
Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917027/ios-steps-to-create-custom-uitableviewcell-with-xib-file

Comment: Ok thank you for the help so far.  So I have created a new xib file with a tableViewCell and added a few labels in it.  Then in my tableviewcontroller I am doing this: 'static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";  CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  if(cell==nil){[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];}  [[cell label1] setText:@"Test"];'  but when I try to access this table view

Comment: I am getting a "terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:...setvalue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryView

Comment: just remade the custom cell and fixed the issue.  Thank you for your help!